# Bulk delete tier price and tier price customer group

Tags: magento-1.8, price, magmi, tierprice

How do you bulk delete tier price and tier price customer group?

Is it possible to do it by Magento Import or Magmi?

Comment: You want to delete all tier prices for all products?

Comment: That is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If it's just an occasional operation and you don't need to automate it just do:

```
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity_tier_price`;
```

And do full reindex afterwards.

Comment: But before you do anything directly in the database do a database backup ;)